# Pass generic list into ObservableCollection constructor

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, observablecollection

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but any particular reason this doesn't work?

```
public ObservableCollection<object> ItemCollection { get; set; }

private void SetListData<T>(List<T> MyList)
{
    ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(MyList);
}
```

Is there some value for T where this won't work?  I figure collection of objects would cover every case, but it seems not:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`<T>`' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`<object>`'

Changing the signature of the property would cause a whole new set of problems, so changing it to:

```
ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(MyList);
```

doesn't seem like a good solution.  Can anyone tell me why my original code doesn't work, and if there is any easy fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

```
private void SetListData<T>(List<T> MyList) where T : class
```

or

```
ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(MyList.Cast<object>());
```

If you had a `List<T>` of a known reference type, it could work, even though the type parameter is not `object`:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var observable = new ObservableCollection<object>(list);
```

But in this case you are using the generic parameter, which is not a known reference type; it could be a value type/struct. These can be "boxed" as `object`s but are not inherently `object`s.

Thus, you must either constrain that parameter to always be a reference type, or allow any type `T` and do an explicit cast to `object` inside the body of the method.

Comment: I think just snippets of code with no explanation are not very useful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this work `where T : class`, I guess it prevents me from passing an interface?

Comment: If you have a list of known type `int`, it wouldn't work (at least not without the `Cast`).

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia It's kind of confusing, but it does not prevent from `T` being an interface. It does prevent it from being a value type (like `int` or a `struct`).

Comment: @Jay Not really, `struct`s can also implement interfaces. `T` cannot be a value type, but the list can contain (boxed) instances of value types.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. `List<T>` is convertible to `IEnumerable<object>` (thanks to covariance) only when `T` is a reference type. So, limiting `T` to be a reference type is going to work:

```
private void SetListData<T>(List<T> MyList) where T : class
{
    ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(MyList);
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing something. The code you posted is identical to the non-working code posted by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "T" is not "object", even though "T" inherits "object".  The types in the generic lists must be the same.

Your best solution would be as follows:

```
ItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
foreach(T item in MyList)
{
    ItemCollection.Add(item);
}
```